# Named Routes Not Recognised in Method When Called From PHPUnit Test

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

When calling a Method from another class that contains a named route the route is not recognised

This PHPUnit test is to check that functionality of the system still meets requirements as the system is complicated.

Testing is run from a local environment (homestead vagrant)

I am calling the method form here:

```
$orderLines = (new EDIProcessController())->getChanges($order['ediOrder'], $order['partnerId']);
```

And the named route that is causing the issue:

```
$orderLine->item_url = route('warehouse.products.view', $itemDetails->id);
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Route [warehouse.products.view] not defined.

/home/vagrant/vr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:305
/home/vagrant/vr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:790
/home/vagrant/vr/app/Http/Controllers/Warehouse/EDI/SPS/EDIProcessController.php:1575
/home/vagrant/vr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:861
/home/vagrant/vr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php:139
/home/vagrant/vr/app/Http/Controllers/Warehouse/EDI/SPS/EDIProcessController.php:1746
```

Route as defined in the routes file:

```
Route::get('/view/{id}', 'Warehouse\ProductController@viewProduct')->name('warehouse.products.view');
```

This route works fine when called from within Laravel app but will not work within PHPUnit test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the answer

There is a issue with using `require_once` for sub route files that is caused due to multiple instances of route files not all getting the required files.

[Here is a dicussion here that I eventually found](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2836)

switching the `require_once` to `require` at all levels of our route files solves the issue